# Coupling at the DB vs an API

Tags: coupling

I have a Website which has a BFF (back end for front end).

It consumes data from a service (a CMS) and its own configuration data.

The CMS data and the apps config data are in separate schemas (so could be in different physical databases)

I need the BFF to decorate config data with cms data

So the options are:

- Querying the database joining the schemas. This clearly adds coupling at the db.
- We could replicate the data.
- Get the data from the CMS api and aggregate in the BFF.

My preference is 3. However when arguing the case other engineers believe 1 and 3 to be just as coupled - the coupling is just moved.

My opinion is coupling at an API is looser than at a db. Also, the more *things* talking to the db the less easy it is to change the db schema for the CMS project.

Thoughts?

Comment: Since it is BFF, what are your front-ends, and what  are your back-ends? A picture, as found on [Sam Newman's page on BFF](https://samnewman.io/patterns/architectural/bff/), would be **really helpful!**